# Changing specific words in string using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have something like this:

```js
var myString = "Paul, Paula, Pauline";
var myRegExp = /Paula?/g;
var change= myString.replace(myRegExp, "George");
document.write(change);
```

How can I change **only** `Paul` and `Paula` without changing `Pauline` into `Georgeine`. Now, I get `George, George, Georgeine`, and I want `George, George, Pauline`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
var myRegExp = /\bPaula?\b/g;
```

```js
var myString = "Paul, Paula, Pauline";
var myRegExp = /\bPaula?\b/g;

var change= myString.replace(myRegExp, "George");

document.write(change);
```

[Word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) (`\b`) are necessary as we need to tell the regex engine to fail the match if there are other word characters other `Paul` or `Paula`.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/FIPdPrrGDlFU-dhJ)

Comment: Glad to help. Please consider upvoting my answer if it proved helpful and accepting since it works for you.

Comment: Actually, sometimes, [debuggex.com](https://www.debuggex.com/) is even more appealing than [regex101.com](http://regex101.com), due to visualization. But it is true that regex101.com is much more helpful since it offers code generation and debugging (shows how the regex actually works). However, for demo purposes, I am relying on SO snippet functionality. See how your question looks now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var myRegExp = /(^|\s)Paula?(?=[,\s]|$)/g
```

You can use this and replace by `var change= myString.replace(myRegExp, "$1George");`

See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fX3oF6/11

Comment: @PiotrX do accept an answer which helped you the most and upvote others which helped you